# php json decode issue

Tags: php, json

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $json;
```

When I use json_decode I get back a JSON tree like this:

```
[
    "name",
    [
        "jason",
        "carl",
        "simpson",
        "crew",
        "marx"
    ]
]
```

So, how can I use `foreach` to get all the name values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
[
    "name",
    [
        "jason",
        "carl",
        "simpson",
        "crew",
        "marx"
    ]
]
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach($data[1] as $name) {
  echo "$name\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php
jason
carl
simpson
crew
marx
```

**EDIT**

Basically The json data is an array, where `$data[0]` is the value name, and `$data[1]` is a subarray that has the names you want

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data[1] as $name_value) {
    // do something with $name_value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was always the same structure, you could just loop over `$data[1]`.

But it looks like it's some sort of key prefix structure. Then for reliability I'd use:

```
$key = array_search("name", $data);

if ($key !== FALSE)
foreach ($data[$key + 1] as $name) {
    print $name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the $data variable now contains a 2-dimensional array.
If you want to get an array of all the names, you say

```
$names=$data['name'];
```

Comment: And where did you get that index from?

Comment: the index should be 'name' not names, will edit that now. but it's the index inside the json data that is associated with the names array.

Comment: It's not a names array, it's a numerically indexed array. To associate name with an array the json would have to look like this `{ 'name' : [] }`

Comment: yes, I know. but it would still be a 2D array with the first dimension being a string, and the second being numerical.

Comment: Whatever the array, `$data['name']` does not exist. Therefore your answer is wrong.